# SQL Server behavior with XML columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have some question about XML columns:

1. when we selecting a XML column and we want to fetch some values (using `XPath`) from its xml contains and perform some operations, does SQL Server read first row and get xml document from hard disk to RAM and perform operation and next fetch next row and so on?
2. if we want bring **ALL** content of xml column to RAM, what we can do?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is getting into SQL Server Internals - SQL Server doesn't read individuals values into RAM, it reads 8k Pages into memory which is how the data is structured on the disk (and the in memory). Your data is stored on one or more of these pages. (I'm keeping this simplified)

If you want to get to understand about how SQL works under the covers, I would recommend the Kalen Delaney - SQL Server Internals book.

Comment: +your post we can use `Table` variable to bring all records to RAM